# I just forked a Repo and RVM wants to install a new version of Ruby. The repo's Gemfile and Gemspec do not specify a Ruby Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, fork

I just forked a Repo and RVM wants to install a new version of Ruby in order to run it.  The repo's Gemfile and Gemspec do not specify a Ruby Version.  I know very little about RVM.  When I try to go ahead with the installation, I get seemingly obscure error messages such as

```
The provided compiler '/usr/bin/gcc' is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
```

and when running bundle install:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Where should I start in order to understand this situation?  Reading 'rvm requirements' made me believe that I needed to install a new binary installer.  That course of action intuitively seems like a rabbit hole.

Thanks in advance, Michael.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the project you just cloned have a `.rvmrc` file included?  If so, this is probably where  the version requirement is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

RVM is trying to compile a Rubygem that the repository is using that has an extension written in C.

You are perhaps getting into problems with compilation due to OSX and GCC